# Show directly from the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(3x)}{3x} = 1$ given $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

We have the definition of what it means to say that $f(x)$ tends to $M \in \mathbb{R}$

It is: $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \space \delta > 0$ such that $x \in (a,b)$ and $0 < |x-c| <\delta \implies |f(x) - M| < \epsilon$.

Now, I understand that we want to show the case is true for $f(3x)$ but directly showing that from the definition is escaping me.

So far I have tried:

Assuming the result true for $y$ and then letting $y=3x$ but I'm not sure that's showing the result directly from the definition.

And I've considered using uniqueness of limits, but the question strictly states no results about limits other than the definition above can be used.

I know that $\sin(3x)$ is bounded between $-1$ and $1$ but I'm not sure how this will help.

In response to a comment:

We know: $0 < |x| < \delta' \implies |\frac{\sin{x}}{x} - 1| < \epsilon'$

and we want to show $0 < |x| < \delta \implies |\frac{\sin{3x}}{3x} - 1| < \epsilon$

Comment: You probably mean limit as $x\to 0$? You can do substitution $t = 3x$ and then we are done.

Comment: You are missing a $\delta$ still in your definition

Comment: @bounceback yes have updated

Comment: @mathreadler yeah that's what I was thinking but I'm not sure that's directly from the definition, is it?

Comment: Start by writing down exactly what you know (in terms of $\delta'$-$\epsilon'$) and what you must prove (in terms of $\delta$-$\epsilon$).

Comment: @TedShifrin I've put that now but don't know where to go from there

Comment: Consider $\delta=\delta'/3$.

Comment: So start by setting $\epsilon'=\epsilon$. Then do the algebra you had in mind.

Comment: Oh, okay okay I finally get it now. For $\delta = \frac{\delta'}{3}$ we have $0 <  |x| < \frac{\delta'}{3} \iff 0 < |3x| < \delta'$ and then we are done because then it's just a case of plugging $3x$ into the known expression. And then yes, I'd set $\epsilon'$ to $\epsilon$ and I'd be done.

Answer (score 3):

We have $f(x) = \frac{\sin{x}}{x}$

We know, for some $\delta > 0$ $$0 < |x| < \delta \implies |f(x) - 1| < \epsilon$$

We want to show, $\exists \space \delta' > 0$ such that $$0 < |x| < \delta' \implies |f(3x) - 1| < \epsilon$$

If we let $\delta'= \frac{\delta}{3}$, we have $$0 < |x| < \frac{\delta}{3} \iff 0 < |3x| < \delta \implies |f(3x) - 1| < \epsilon.$$

And we are done.

Comment: There you go. :)